# How to convert a pandas column of json strings into a new dataframe

Tags: json, csv, pandas

I've been given a csv in which a column of the data is a json strings which looks like the following when loaded into pandas:

```
df.registered_office.head()


3    {u"country": u"United Kingdom", u"region": None, u"postal_code": u"ST6 3HL", u"street_address": u"Martin Leake House Waterloo Road\nCobridge", u"locality": u"Stoke On Trent"}
5             {u"country": u"England", u"region": None, u"postal_code": u"BS32 4JY", u"street_address": u"Woodlands Grange Woodlands Lane\nBradley Stoke", u"locality": u"Bristol"}
7       {u"country": u"United Kingdom", u"region": u"Staffordshire", u"postal_code": u"ST6 8JD", u"street_address": u"136 Knypersley Road\nNorton", u"locality": u"Stoke On Trent"}
8    {u"country": u"United Kingdom", u"region": u"Staffordshire", u"postal_code": u"ST9 9HQ", u"street_address": u"Ashlands\n253 Leek Road, Endon", u"locality": u"Stoke On Trent"}
9                      {u"country": u"United Kingdom", u"region": None, u"postal_code": u"ST1 5TA", u"street_address": u"C/O Kpmg Festival Way\nStoke On Trent", u"locality": None}
Name: registered_address, dtype: object
```

What's the most pythonic way to transform this column into either a new dataframe or into new columns based on the various keys?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use [`DataFrame.from_records`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.from_records.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'registered_office':[
{u"country": u"United Kingdom", u"region": None, u"postal_code": u"ST6 3HL", u"street_address": u"Martin Leake House Waterloo Road\nCobridge", u"locality": u"Stoke On Trent"},
{u"country": u"England", u"region": None, u"postal_code": u"BS32 4JY", u"street_address": u"Woodlands Grange Woodlands Lane\nBradley Stoke", u"locality": u"Bristol"},
{u"country": u"United Kingdom", u"region": u"Staffordshire", u"postal_code": u"ST6 8JD", u"street_address": u"136 Knypersley Road\nNorton", u"locality": u"Stoke On Trent"},
{u"country": u"United Kingdom", u"region": u"Staffordshire", u"postal_code": u"ST9 9HQ", u"street_address": u"Ashlands\n253 Leek Road, Endon", u"locality": u"Stoke On Trent"},
{u"country": u"United Kingdom", u"region": None, u"postal_code": u"ST1 5TA", u"street_address": u"C/O Kpmg Festival Way\nStoke On Trent", u"locality": None}
]})
```

```
print (pd.DataFrame.from_records(df.registered_office.values.tolist()))
          country        locality postal_code         region  \
0  United Kingdom  Stoke On Trent     ST6 3HL           None   
1         England         Bristol    BS32 4JY           None   
2  United Kingdom  Stoke On Trent     ST6 8JD  Staffordshire   
3  United Kingdom  Stoke On Trent     ST9 9HQ  Staffordshire   
4  United Kingdom            None     ST1 5TA           None   

                                   street_address  
0      Martin Leake House Waterloo Road\nCobridge  
1  Woodlands Grange Woodlands Lane\nBradley Stoke  
2                     136 Knypersley Road\nNorton  
3                  Ashlands\n253 Leek Road, Endon  
4           C/O Kpmg Festival Way\nStoke On Trent
```

Comment: Thank you for your swift response. It's almost worked, but it's split individual characters in the string into columns, rather than keys.

Comment: So you need transpose? `print (pd.DataFrame.from_records(df.registered_office.values.tolist()).T)` ?

Comment: Your output is different?

Comment: Sorry. I lost my web connection. Here was my reply: Sorry, I'm probably not very clear. The output (using the T method) outputs on first row { { { { { { { { { { (one for each column), u u u u u u u u u u (Unicode) on the next and then ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' on the next.

Comment: Are data confidental?

Comment: It's generated from the OpenCorporates website. I could provide you with a proper sample if that helps. (I appreciate your help.)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124447/discussion-between-elksie5000-and-jezrael).

Comment: Now I am not in work and so I cannot help you more. But I think if you send me on my email (in my profile) your full file, tomorrow I can help you.

Comment: Will do. Thank you.